# Problem for mutate in dplyr: which.max() returns integer(0) instead of NA

Tags: r, dplyr

I am creating a master dataset. I need to calculate a new variable which returns the column position of the maximum value in each row. It is real life data so there are missing observations throughout the master dataset.

```
data.frame(v1 = c(3,2,NA,6),
           v2 = c(NA,1,6,7),
           v3 = c(1,1,NA,1)) -> df1

df1

# output
#
#   v1 v2 v3
# 1  3 NA  1
# 2  2  1  1
# 3 NA  6 NA
# 4  6  7  1
```

What I need can be calculated easily using `which.max` within `mutate()` in dplyr.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  rowwise %>%
    mutate(maxCol = which.max(c_across(everything())))

# Ouput
#
# A tibble: 4 × 4
# Rowwise: 
#      v1    v2    v3 maxCol
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <int>
# 1     3    NA     1      1
# 2     2     1     1      1
# 3    NA     6    NA      2
# 4     6     7     1      2
```

If there are NAs in a row which.max simply ignores them. However if a row has ALL NAs...

```
data.frame(v1 = c(3,2,NA,6),
           v2 = c(NA,1,NA,7),
           v3 = c(1,1,NA,1)) -> df2

df2

# output
#
#   v1 v2 v3
# 1  3 NA  1
# 2  2  1  1
# 3 NA NA NA
# 4  6  7  1
```

...we run into a problem

```
df2 %>%
  rowwise %>%
    mutate(maxCol = which.max(c_across(everything())))

# Error in `mutate()`:
#   ℹ In argument: `maxCol = which.max(c_across(everything()))`.
# ℹ In row 3.
# Caused by error:
#   ! `maxCol` must be size 1, not 0.
# ℹ Did you mean: `maxCol = list(which.max(c_across(everything())))` ?
#   Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

If we follow the advice in the error message we CAN calculate a variable by putting everything into a list

```
df2 %>%
  rowwise %>%
    mutate(maxCol = list(which.max(c_across(everything())))) -> dfList

dfList

# output
#
# A tibble: 4 × 4
# Rowwise: 
#      v1    v2    v3 maxCol   
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <list>   
# 1     3    NA     1 <int [1]>
# 2     2     1     1 <int [1]>
# 3    NA    NA    NA <int [0]>
# 4     6     7     1 <int [1]>
```

However this creates all sorts of other problems. For example if you `unlist()` the `maxCol` variable it returns 3 values instead of 4.

Can anyone suggest a way around this using dplyr, whereby `which.max` returns `NA` when it encounters a row with all `NA` rather than returning `integer(0)`? Or maybe an alternative approach within dplyr using another function?

I can't simply remove the rows with all NA for the variables in question from the master dataset because the rows in question are only all NA for the variables used to calculate the new variable, i.e. they have valid observations for other variables that prevent me from deleting them listwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use an `ifelse` to catch all rows with `NA` (set these rows to `NA`, if not, proceed with your command).

```r
library(dplyr)

df2 %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(which.max = ifelse(all(is.na(c_across(everything()))), NA, which.max(c_across(everything()))))

# A tibble: 4 × 4
# Rowwise: 
     v1    v2    v3 which.max
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <int>
1     3    NA     1         1
2     2     1     1         1
3    NA    NA    NA        NA
4     6     7     1         2
```