# Difference between ifelse and if_else for conditionals returning NA

Tags: r, dplyr

I can't work this out.

I posted [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76320674/problem-for-mutate-in-dplyr-which-max-returns-integer0-instead-of-na) asking how to apply `which.max` rowwise in dplyr. I got a great answer that solved my problem. However, as often happens, getting one question answered raised another one. I will lay the problem out with some toy data

Here is a data frame with three variables.

```
data.frame(v1 = c(3,2,NA,6),
           v2 = c(NA,1,NA,7),
           v3 = c(1,1,NA,1)) -> df2

df2

# output
#
#   v1 v2 v3
# 1  3 NA  1
# 2  2  1  1
# 3 NA NA NA
# 4  6  7  1
```

Using `which.max` within dplyr, I want to calculate a new variable that returns the column position of the maximum value in each row. However, for reasons explained in my previous post linked above, if the row is *all* NA I want it to return `NA` instead of `integer(0)`. So I use `ifelse` to apply a conditional whereby if the row is all `NA` it returns NA and, if not, it performs the rowwise `which.max` operation.

```
library(dplyr)

df2 %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(maxCol = ifelse(test = all(is.na(c_across(everything()))),
                           yes = NA, 
                           no = which.max(c_across(everything()))))

# output
# # A tibble: 4 × 4
# # Rowwise: 
#      v1    v2    v3 maxCol
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <int>
# 1     3    NA     1      1
# 2     2     1     1      1
# 3    NA    NA    NA     NA
# 4     6     7     1      2
```

However if I do the same thing using the dplyr `if_else` verb it throws an error.

```
df2 %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(maxCol = if_else(condition = all(is.na(c_across(everything()))), 
                          true = NA, 
                          false = which.max(c_across(everything()))))

# Error in `mutate()`:
# ℹ In argument: `maxCol = if_else(...)`.
# ℹ In row 3.
# Caused by error in `if_else()`:
# ! `false` must have size 1, not size 0.
# Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

**Why is this happening?** and how do I make `if_else` work the same way as `ifelse`?

Comment: if you search for the definition `dplyr::if_else` you will understand. true and false values and condion all need to be of same type .

Comment: Thank you @Triparna Poddar. What do mean by the 'same type'?

Comment: `if_else` always checks the output of `TRUE` and `FALSE`, which `ifesle` does not. This is to ensure consistent output of the new vector (e.g., all  are characters). As such, when you arrive at row 3, the `FALSE` statement will return a vector of length 0, which is not allowed (even if the `TRUE` statement is valid).

Answer (score 1):

My solution (to the given problem) would be to not use `ifelse` or `if_else`. To me, the easiest appears to be to define the following:

```
which.max2 <- function(x) {
  x <- which.max(x)
  if (length(x) == 0) {
    NA
  } else {
    x
  }
}
```

And then run:

```
df2 %>% 
  mutate(
    maxCol = apply(across(everything()), 1, which.max2)
  )
```

Alternatively, we could put it in the the `if_else` statement:

```
df2 %>% 
  mutate(
    maxCol = if_else(if_all(everything(), is.na),
      NA,
      apply(across(everything()), 1, which.max2)
    )
  )
```

But that is just more verbose.

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate the insights from the comments (and answer the "why" question), consider the output of

```r
if_else(all(is.na(c(NA,NA,NA))),
        NA,
        which.max(c(NA,0,NA)))
# [1] NA
```

compared to

```r
if_else(all(is.na(c(NA,NA,NA))),
        NA,
        which.max(c(NA,NA,NA)))
# Error in `if_else()`:
# ! `false` must have size 1, not size 0.
# Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

where the latter is what is happening in your code. `if_else` is trying to evaluate the false statement, even though the condition is true. The output of `which.max(c(NA,NA,NA))` is `integer(0)`, which `if_else` really does not like.

Because of this, the second part of your question (how do I make `if_else` work the same way as `ifelse`) could only be obtained through `tryCatch()`, or through some verbose workaround, as the other answer suggests.